# Android studio firebase database retrieve child value for multiple childs

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database firebase which stores user data. I want to display all of the this data as separate textviews in "My Account" fragment.

I have managed to load the data into the textview but i dont think this is the best way to do it as it requires alot of code for each textView.

Can you help me out and improve this code, so that i will not have to make new database references for each textView and attach a listener to each.

The textViews are;
Name, Surname, SID, Email and Username

```
 textViewName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

    //code goes here that is not to do with the fargments or in onCreate View
    FirebaseUser loggedinFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
    String userId = loggedinFirebaseUser.getUid();

    //stores the reference as a string to be passed onto the userDataReference table
    databaseNameUrlRef = "users/userData" + "/" + userId;

    userDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(databaseNameUrlRef + "/name");

    //Retrieve all user data and store and display in correct textviews

   userDataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           String Name = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
           textViewName.setText(Name);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
```

[This is the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0053m.png)

Comment: You can use `recyclerview` for this task.

Comment: Have a look at [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), which provides adapters from a Firebase query/reference to ListView or RecyclerView (as Heisen-Berg says, those are the typical UI controls to use for such repeating constructs).

Answer (score 0):

Create an `User` object.

```
userDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/userData");
userDataRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
     public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
         User newUser = (User) dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
         //Now you can assign values to your textview by retrieving userdata from user object
    }
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        User user = (User) dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
    }
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //...
    }
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        //...
    }
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        //...
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!